# How do I find the range of the following function?

Tags: functions

The question says to find the **range** *and* **domain** of $$P(x) = \frac{\sin(x)-1}{\sqrt{3-2\sin(x)-2\cos(x)}}$$

How do I approach this problem? For domain, I know I should set the denominator $>0$ so that it doesn't become undefined...but not really how to proceed further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It probably helps to observe that $2 \sin x + 2 \cos x = 2 \sqrt{2}(\sin x \cos \frac{\pi}{4} + \cos x \sin \frac{\pi}{4}) = 2 \sqrt {2} \sin (x+ \frac{\pi}{4})$.

Comment: You would set the denominator $>0$ to find the domain, not range

Comment: @ShubhamJohri yes sorry it was a typo, I'm on mobile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that

$$3-2\sin(x)-2\cos(x) = 2 + \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)-2\cos(x)$$ $$= (\sin^2(x) - 2\sin(x) + 1) + (\cos^2(x) - 2\cos(x) + 1) = (\sin(x)-1)^2 + (\cos(x)-1)^2$$

In other words our function can be rewritten as

$$P(x) = \frac{\sin(x)-1}{\sqrt{(\sin(x)-1)^2 + (\cos(x)-1)^2}}$$

The numerator is always nonpositive, at most $0$. To get the minimum negative value,

$$\frac{\sin(x)-1}{\sqrt{(\sin(x)-1)^2 + (\cos(x)-1)^2}} \geq \frac{\sin(x)-1}{\sqrt{(\sin(x)-1)^2}} = -1$$

which is okay because both squares inside the square root cannot be $0$ at the same time.

So the range of this function is $[-1,0]$.

Comment: Could you please explain the last step....how you got the minimum negative value

Comment: @Techie5879 Take absolute value instead and denote $a = 1-\sin(x)$ and $b=1-\cos(x)$. Then $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \leq \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2}} = 1$. The minus sign flips the inequality.